# Schedule sharedPreferences data to be cleared at night

Tags: android, kotlin, datetime, checkbox, sharedpreferences

I have an activity with several checkboxes that their check/uncheck status is saved throughout the day by sharedPreferences. These checkboxes are daily tasks that need to be reset to the unchecked state at some point each night. It does not have to be an exact time. The app and device will be closed at this time as it is after work hours.

Not sure how to code this utilizing the time of day.

What would be your recommendation on how to do this? I'm programming in Kotlin.

Comment: AlarmManager or WorkManager

Comment: Your other option is to store a timestamp in the shared prefs too, say the time the next clear should happen. When the user next runs the app, during initialisation (e.g. in your main `Activity` or an `Application` class) it checks if *now > clearTime* and if so, it clears all the boxes and updates `clearTime` to *"tonight"*. That way the reset happens when the user is about to use the app, and you don't need to worry about things like the schedule being missed (e.g. the phone is turned off, and when it's turned on the app is run immediately)

Comment: Yes, that's better.

Comment: Use WorkManager - with periodicworkrequest set time interval as day and unit as 1 and schedule it in night for the first time. I hope this will work.